# Laravel 5.2 : Can I use a custom laravel facade in multiple classes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, facade, laravel-facade

I am learning about Laravel facades in Laravel version 5.2, and I made my own facade to use in multiple custom classes of my own, so I don't have repeating code. However I've been getting the following problem.

I've referenced the Facade Alias under the namespace in my class like this: `use FacadeAlias`, however when I use this in two classes It gives me the following **error:**

> Cannot use FacadeAlias as FacadeAlias because name is already in use

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: Try to use Fully-Qualified Classname like `\App\MyFacadeClass\FacadeAlias`. Make sure you've read the Laravel Facades documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades